# Overload operator= to exchange data between to classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'd like to use two classes `A` and `B` for some different types of task. But i want to exchange some data, which should be similar in both, so i'd like to use a `A = B` for ex.

So, how to use this, with avoiding two-way including in header files?

Example:
in class_a.h:

```
#include class_b.h
class A {
  private:
    int i;
  public:
    A& operator=(B& const b);
}
```

class_b.h:

```
#include class_a.h // won't work here ...
class B {
  private:
    unsigned long n;
  public:
    B& operator=(A& const a);
}
```

Comment: Why do they need to be in different header files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must forward-declare the other class:

```
class B;
class A {
  private:
    int i;
  public:
    A& operator=(B& const b);
}
```

Also note that you should probably declare `friend class B;` inside the definition of `A` if you don't have getters and need to access `B::n`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a forward declaration:

```
class A;

class B {
  private:
    unsigned long n;
  public:
    B& operator=(A& const a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily better but consider also the idea not to override the assignment, but provide conversions.

You can do like

```
#include "b.h"
class A
{
public:
    A(const B&);
    operator B() const;
};
```

If you do `a=b;` it will become implicitly `a=A(b)` and if you do `b=a;` will become implicitly `b=a.operator B();`

This is like saying that B can be "promoted" to A and A "demoted" to B.
But you can do all around A, not modifying B.